# Contentful Video Content

Tags: content-management-system, contentful

How does contentful return video content? Is it returned in JSON format or is it returned as a binary data stream? Contentful's delivery api always seems to return REST response ,however I am not sure how video content is returned and served.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Video, and any other kinds of media are stored as Assets. When you get an Asset from the REST API it is returned as JSON, with a property containing a url to the relevant media file stored in that asset.

You can see that in this particular example from the API docs:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "title": "Nyan Cat",
    "file": {
      "fileName": "Nyan_cat_250px_frame.png",
      "contentType": "image/png",
      "url": "//images.contentful.com/cfexampleapi/4gp6taAwW4CmSgumq2ekUm/9da0cd1936871b8d72343e895a00d611/Nyan_cat_250px_frame.png",
      "details": {
        "image": {
          "width": 250,
          "height": 250
        },
        "size": 12273
      }
    }
  },
  "sys": {
    ...
  }
}
```

In this case it's an image, but if it was a video you'd have a video url instead and the relevant content type.

More details here https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/assets/assets-collection/get-a-single-asset?console=1

Comment: Thank you ! Does this enable content to be stored in CDN and separates template from actual content ?